# Changing the submitted value onSubmit using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two fields that usually work as they should and submit. 
their IDs and names are 'location_names' and 'sub_cat'

My script is complete except for the fact that I want the 'sub_cat' field value to be ignored (it is completely ignored now) only when the value is '-10' and for it to replace 'location_names' if the value IS NOT '-10'. I had several failed attempts at doing this, all of them just ignore the values or return null. I wonder if I should use regular javascript instead? Any help at all is appreciated.

Code description:

```
 onSubmit{
 if (sub_cat != '-10') {
 location_names.value = sub_cat.value;
 }
 else {
 // do nothing
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/959JY/)?

- a "return false" statement prevents you from actually submitting the form
- basically, by creating a $("#form").submit event handler in JavaScript (jQuery), you'll be able to catch the event before actually submitting the data to the server.

Comment: Almost... I managed to get the coding to work and after debugging it with alert() I know what I'm missing... I only need to know how I can replace the values since $mainCats===$subCats; doesn't work. So what's the correct way to do it?

Comment: Most helpful reply but still my code didn't work. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should some thing like below when caparisoning of numbers in JS

```
if (parseInt(sub_cat, 10) != -10) {
   location_names.value = sub_cat.value;
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose sub_cat is the element, i.e, `sub_cat = $('#sub_cat');`

In this case:

```
onSubmit {

    if (parseInt(sub_cat.val(), 10) != -10)
         location_names.val() = sub_cat.val();

    // Add this if you don't want to submit the form when the value is -10.
    return false;

}
```